# General and particular solution for a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I'm given the matrix A and a vector b:

\begin{equation}
A= \begin{pmatrix}
9 &-12 \\ 
6 & -9 
\end{pmatrix},\;  b= \binom{7}{5}
\end{equation}
I have calculated the two eigenvalues and eigenvectors as:

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{1}=3,\;  \lambda_{2}=-3 \; \;  and \; \; 
v_{1}= \binom{2}{1},\;  v_{2}= \binom{1}{1}
\end{equation}

The I found the general solution to A by:
\begin{equation}
x'(t)=Ax(t)
\end{equation}

This gives me:
\begin{equation}
x=c_{1}\binom{2}{1}e^{3t}+c_{2}\binom{1}{1}e^{-3t}
\end{equation}

Is that correct so far?

Then I have to give the particular solution that satisfies:

\begin{equation}
x(0)=b
\end{equation}

And now I'm stuck as I don't know how to proceed (b is the vector given above).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x(0)=c_1\binom{2}{1}+c_2\binom{1}{1}=\binom{2c_1+c_2}{c_1+c_2}=\binom{7}{5}$$
$$\therefore c_1=2, c_2=3$$

Comment: Thank you for this - didn't think it was that easy. So my general solution was correct?